Where is Sunrise Airline check in at Edinburgh airport?
Where is check in for Sunrise Airlines at Edinburgh airport ?

Are you sure the airline name is Sunrise Airline(s)? Where are you flying to, on what date, at what time, and what is the flight number?

I have checked with Edinburgh Airport - there is no Sunrise Airlines listed. In fact the only Sunrise Airways I could find globally is a Caribbean regional airline.

There’s only one terminal at Edinburgh Airport, so it’s there.
When you arrive, look at the screens listing all departures, find your flight, and it will tell you to which desks you should go for check-in.
